# When will dark theme on Azure DevOps be enabled?

Tags: azure-devops

[Sprint 142](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-142-update#dark-theme) updates indicate Azure DevOps now supports a dark theme. It suggests that underneath your avatar in the top right of every page, you can turn it on by selecting theme.

I see no `Theme` option, as per the link. How is the feature enabled or is there a timeline for general release?

[image: Image from Az. DevOps]

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting this update. I can able to get that menu under my account.As a workaround can you try the `preview features` and enable the `experimental themes`

Comment: I don't have it also and I don't have `experimental themes` under `preview features` :|

Comment: Thanks @Jayendran - that feature isn't present either for our subscription. Wondering if there's a way to manually enable it at the organization-level, or if we just have to wait :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevOps Theme Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uchFa.png)

I found it and here it is shown in the new dark theme preview.

Comment: Neat! You're one of the lucky ones :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that's easy to miss in that post, is toward the bottom... "These features will be rolling out over the next two to three weeks."

New sprints are deployed in a phased approach, so it might take a little time to get a given release.